# db backup fail, cannot allocate memory

Tags: postgresql, backup

We've got 325GB large postgres database on windows (`PostgreSQL 12.8, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`) with a failing database backup with the following message (names of the table and the columns are changed):

```
pg_dump: error: Dumping the contents of table "tbl" failed: PQgetResult() failed.
pg_dump: error: Error message from server: ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 18446744073709551613
pg_dump: error: The command was: COPY tbl (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8) TO stdout;
```

The size of the table is

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('tbl'))
89 GB
```

the schema of the table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl
(
    a1 uuid,
    a2 character varying(8) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    a3 character varying(8) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    a4 character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    a5 timestamp without time zone,
    a6 uuid[],
    a7 uuid,
    a8 uuid
)
```

(without any indexes or primary keys). We believe that the size of the array should not exceed 10k elements, but one cannot exclude software bugs.

No antivirus is visible on the system (it is a VM with an SSD as a drive). The data is inserted through JEE application.

How can one further analyze the problem?

Comment: Can you try to run the dump from a linux machine on the same LAN?

Comment: 12.9 is out for a month.  You should try that.  I have no reason to think it will fix the problem, but that is the first thing to exclude

Comment: Hi @jjanes, thanks for the comment. Unfortunately the system runs in the customer environment which has a very limited access and pretty much inaccessible from other machines..

Comment: Given that this is 18 EB, I would suspect data corruption.